# List table validation rules/checks in FoxPro

Tags: validation, visual-foxpro

I need to check and see if a validation rule exists on a table and/or field in FoxPro (to determine programmatically if it should be replaced/added/removed). `DISPLAY STRUCTURE` doesn't include any validation rules.

Is there a VFP command to list out validation rules on a table (to an array, file, cursor, anything)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DBGETPROP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977505(v=vs.71).aspx) to get information for a single DB-object/field:

```
? DBGETPROP("mytable.myfield","Field","RuleExpression")
```

or for a table:

```
? DBGETPROP("mytable", "Table", "RuleExpression")
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that [`AFIELDS()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kd8d4ez%28v=vs.80%29.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kd8d4ez%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`COPY STRUCTURE EXTENDED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e95wkaah%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) both include field and table validation rules.

For `AFIELDS()` the table expression is stored on the first row of the array in column 10, and the field validation expression is stored with each row in column 7.

For `COPY STRUCTURE EXTENDED` the table expression is in the first row in a memo column called `table_rule` and the field expression is stored with each rule in a memo column called `field_rule`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the GenDBC utility that comes with VFP. It generates a program that recreates the database.

Comment: It would be comparatively quite difficult to analyze GenDBC output programmatically.

Comment: Ah, missed that you wanted to evaluate the result programmatically.